# Detect Payload when promise resolves or rejects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

**Conceptual Question**

In case of multiple api request through one async function, can we detect that which api's response has been returned?

for example: there is a method `foo` which is fired onClick of a button. It takes an `id` and called 10 times with different ids. Now in response, is it possible to detect that which id's response this is?

```
const obj = {};

const setObj = (id, val) => {
   obj = { ...obj, [id]: value };
}

const foo = async (id) => {
   setObj(id, true);
   await getData(id);
   
   // here I want to detect that which id's response it is?
   setObj(id, false);
}
```

Comment: the async response you get from `getData(id)` should be the response for `id`.

Comment: since.. it is await call.. the id in setObj will point to the same id the api call was made for..

Comment: @Joe for e.g. `foo` is called in this sequence. 1, 2, 3. but id = 2 takes longer and so it resolves like 1, 3, 2. Now if I `console.log(id)` after `await`, will it console 1, 2, 3 or 1, 3, 2?

Comment: The logging order is irrelevant, isn't it? The `id` variable will have the correct value anyway. Maybe you should add a [mcve] and/or explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: @str it involves api calling so can't produce a working example. If `id` variable will have the correct value then the logging order should be 1,3,2?

Comment: If 1 is the fastest and 2 the slowest, then it probably resolves in the order 1,3,2. But given your example, the order is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @str I am asking the same in the example. I have to remove the resolved id from an array so I need to know that which has been resolved. You said probably, if 2 resolves at last then it should be consoled last. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can detect that which id's response is that. Below is the example code which verifies that.

```js
const getData = (id) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('succcess!');
    }, id === 2 ? 3000 : id === 1 ? 2000 :1000);
  });
};

const foo = async (id) => {
    await getData(id);
  console.log(id);
}

foo(1);
foo(2);
foo(3);
```